# Getting CSS Properties and writing to the page live with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to get the names and values of CSS properties and write them to the page. The problem is the values don't change live i.e., e.g. the opacity should show a decreasing value from 1 to 0 live. Also the padding, border and margin values are not shown. This can be seen by opening up the page in firefox and using firebug to inspect it.

**The Markup**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="box">click to hide me</div>
    <p id="result">&nbsp;</p>
</div>
```

**The Styles**

```
#container {
    overflow: auto;
}

#box {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 5px solid black;
    margin: 15px;
    background-color: red;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
}

#result {
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    background-color: #EEE;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
```

**The Script**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#box" ).click(function() {
        var html = [ "The clicked div has the following styles:" ];
        var styleProps = $( this ).css(["width", "height", "padding", "border", "margin", "opacity", "display"]);
        $.each( styleProps, function( prop, value ) {
            html.push( prop + ": " + value );
        });
        $( "#result" ).html( html.join( "<br>" ) );
    });

    $("#box").click(function() {
        $("#box").hide(5000);
    });
});
```

Just to be clear I am noob with jQuery/javascript and I am trying to find out which and what values the jQuery hide() method changes. Using firebug in firefox I see that the the height, width, border, padding, margin, opacity and display are nulled. I am trying to show that in the page itself in the result div.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7SjZL/1/)

Comment: You're not updating the DOM after setting it in your first click callback(the one that sets the values). You should look into a function like window.setInterval or requestAnimationFrame to update the DOM with the values on an interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several issues here.

1. You cannot get `margin`, `padding`, and `border` css properties in one go. You need to get something like `marginTop`, `paddingBottom`, `borderWidth` and so on.
2. You need to get status update to separate function, an then call it on `progress` of your hide.

   ```
   $.fn.update = function(element) {
       var html = [ "The clicked div has the following styles:" ];
       var styleProps = $( this ).css(["width", "height", "opacity", "display"]);
       $.each( styleProps, function( prop, value ) {
           html.push( prop + ": " + value );
       });
       element.html(html.join("<br>"));
   }

   var box = $("#box");

   box.click(function() {
       box.hide({
           duration: 5000, 
           progress: function() {
               box.update($("#result"));
           }
       });
   });
   ```

[Fiddle for ya](http://jsfiddle.net/7SjZL/7/)

Comment: the display property still shows block instead of null.

Comment: great. I can push in the individual box model properties in there too?